# capistrano doesn't use gem path; should I add? best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rvm, capistrano

I'm just getting my first rails app deployed to a linode instance. I think / hope that I'm like 90% of the way there.

One question I have is the best practice for gem path. I'm using rvm and my gem environment looks like this (whole thing for completion):

```
root@dev:~# gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.10
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     -  http://rubygems.org/
```

Based upon deploy, my gems are stored in default:
/data/sites/jt/apps/test-app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems

This means that for example 
gem show rails

gives me a command not found. What is the best place to centralize this for end users and capistrano? What is the best practice for handling this (should I just sym link in the rails command)?

As an aside, I'm running ruby 1.9.2. Why is the shared/bundle telling me 1.9.1?

thx for any help

Comment: What does your Gemfile.lock say?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved it already?

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano uses shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1 by default nothing to do with your ruby version.
Can you see your gems installed when running

```
$ bundle show rails
```

or

```
$ bundle exec gem list
```

?